# Replace multiple columns' NaNs with other columns' values in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given a dataframe as follows:

```
      date city  gdp  gdp1  gdp2  gross domestic product  pop  pop1  pop2
0  2001-03   bj  3.0   NaN   NaN                     NaN  7.0   NaN   NaN
1  2001-06   bj  5.0   NaN   NaN                     NaN  6.0   6.0   NaN
2  2001-09   bj  8.0   NaN   NaN                     8.0  4.0   4.0   NaN
3  2001-12   bj  7.0   NaN   7.0                     NaN  2.0   NaN   2.0
4  2001-03   sh  4.0   4.0   NaN                     NaN  3.0   NaN   NaN
5  2001-06   sh  5.0   NaN   NaN                     5.0  5.0   5.0   NaN
6  2001-09   sh  9.0   NaN   NaN                     NaN  4.0   4.0   NaN
7  2001-12   sh  3.0   3.0   NaN                     NaN  6.0   NaN   6.0
```

I want to replace `NaN`s from `gdp` and `pop` with values of `gdp1`, `gdp2`, `gross domestic product` and `pop1`, `pop2` respectively.

```
      date city  gdp  pop
0  2001-03   bj    3    7
1  2001-06   bj    5    6
2  2001-09   bj    8    4
3  2001-12   bj    7    2
4  2001-03   sh    4    3
5  2001-06   sh    5    5
6  2001-09   sh    9    4
7  2001-12   sh    3    6
```

The following code works, but I wonder if it's possible to make it more concise, since I have many similar columns?

```
df.loc[df['gdp'].isnull(), 'gdp'] = df['gdp1']
df.loc[df['gdp'].isnull(), 'gdp'] = df['gdp2']
df.loc[df['gdp'].isnull(), 'gdp'] = df['gross domestic product']
df.loc[df['pop'].isnull(), 'pop'] = df['pop1']
df.loc[df['pop'].isnull(), 'pop'] = df['pop2']
df.drop(['gdp1', 'gdp2', 'gross domestic product', 'pop1', 'pop2'], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is use back filling missing values filtered by [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html), if possible more values per group then is prioritize columns from left side, if change `.bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]` to `.ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]` then is prioritize columns from right side:

```
#if first column is gdp, pop
df['gdp'] = df.filter(like='gdp').bfill(axis=1)['gdp']
df['pop'] = df.filter(like='pop').bfill(axis=1)['pop']

#if possible any first column
df['gdp'] = df.filter(like='gdp').bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
df['pop'] = df.filter(like='pop').bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
```

But if only one non missing values is posible use `max`, `min`...:

```
df['gdp'] = df.filter(like='gdp').max(axis=1)
df['pop'] = df.filter(like='pop').max(axis=1)
```

If need specify columns names by list:

```
gdp_c = ['gdp1','gdp2','gross domestic product']
pop_c = ['pop1','pop2']
df['gdp'] = df[gdp_c].bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
df['pop'] = df[pop_c].bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
```

---

```
df = df[['date','city','gdp','pop']]
print (df)

      date city  gdp  pop
0  2001-03   bj  3.0  7.0
1  2001-06   bj  5.0  6.0
2  2001-09   bj  8.0  4.0
3  2001-12   bj  7.0  2.0
4  2001-03   sh  4.0  3.0
5  2001-06   sh  5.0  5.0
6  2001-09   sh  9.0  4.0
7  2001-12   sh  3.0  6.0
```

Comment: Why not `df.filter(like='gdp').bfill(axis=1)['gdp']`?

Comment: Sorry, `filter` is a good idea, you may keep it in aswer. But in my data there `gdp` type columns which have no similarity with from words. Please check the update of example data.

Comment: So I need set columns name which need to replace for `gdp` and `pop` instead of using `filter` method.

Comment: Yes, almost, I think I will need to set order of columns names first before using `bfill` method in case if columns name doesn't follow the order as example.

Comment: @ahbon - I think this order is by list of columns names, e.g. `gdp_c = ['gdp1','gdp2','gross domestic product']` then if select then `gross domestic product` is last one.

Comment: You're right, not necessary to set order for `df` at first step. :)